# Help needed with the most trivial protobuf-net example 3

Tags: .net, protobuf-net

Given:

```
public class E
{
  public object Y { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying the following code:

```
var m = RuntimeTypeModel.Default;
m.Add(typeof(E), false).Add("Y");
// m.Add(typeof(object), false).AddSubType(1, typeof(int));

var e = new E { Y = 5 };
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
  m.Serialize(ms, e);
  ms.Position = 0;
  var e2 = (E)m.Deserialize(ms, null, typeof(E));
  Debug.Assert(e.Y.Equals(e2.Y));
}
```

It fails with:

```
System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  Message=No serializer defined for type: System.Object
  Source=protobuf-net
  StackTrace:
       at ProtoBuf.Meta.ValueMember.GetCoreSerializer(Type type, WireType& defaultWireType, Boolean asReference, Boolean dynamicType) in C:\Work\protobuf-net-v2\protobuf-net\Meta\ValueMember.cs:line 398
  InnerException:
```

So, I uncomment the third line, but then I get:

```
System.ArgumentException occurred
  Message=Not valid for primitive types
Parameter name: type
  Source=protobuf-net
  ParamName=type
  StackTrace:
       at ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType..ctor(RuntimeTypeModel model, Type type) in C:\Work\protobuf-net-v2\protobuf-net\Meta\MetaType.cs:line 166
  InnerException:
```

Hence, the question is - how do I (de)serialize an object property containing a **primitive** boxed value type instance?

Note, that the same approach does work with a non primitive value type, like DateTime (of course, I had to use a surrogate).

**EDIT**

If I comment the primitivity check in method `ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.MetaType`, then the following code works correctly:

```
static void Main()
{
  var m = RuntimeTypeModel.Default;
  m.Add(typeof(E), false).Add("Y");
  m.Add(typeof(object), false).AddSubType(1, typeof(int));
  m.Add(typeof(IntSurrogate), false).Add("Value");
  m.Add(typeof(int), false).SetSurrogate(typeof(IntSurrogate));

  var e = new E { Y = 5 };
  using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    m.Serialize(ms, e);
    ms.Position = 0;
    var e2 = (E)m.Deserialize(ms, null, typeof(E));
    Debug.Assert(e.Y.Equals(e2.Y));
  }
}

internal class IntSurrogate
{
  public static implicit operator int(IntSurrogate surrogate)
  {
    return surrogate.Value;
  }
  public static implicit operator IntSurrogate(int v)
  {
    return new IntSurrogate { Value = v };
  }

  internal int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Of course, I would like to see it work without the need for `IntSurrogate`.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure this qualifies as "trivial" - try it with XmlSerializer, DataContractSerializer, etc - AFAIK they will *all* fail here

Comment: @Marc - Sorry, it seemed trivial to me. I am using CSLA mobile serialization, which allows it. We have a problem that we need to port an existing application, so that it no longer uses CSLA. It is a long a painful process and dismissing the mobile serialization is the first and very important step. Is there a conceptual difficulty to handle the presented case? After all, it works with non primitive value types (through the surrogates, of course).

Comment: @mark - the dynamic type option would probably work, but it might be quite expensive on the wire

Comment: @marc - I would like to understand what is the conceptual problem? As I see it, protobuf-net has already diverged from the original intention of the google protocol buffers. People want to use as the replacement of the standard serialization facilities found in .NET and even more so in Silverlight. This is the impression I get from browsing the web. And this is certainly true for me. Of course, if I was designing a new system, I would not stumble upon these problems of integeres boxed as objects traveling over the wire. Alas, this is not the case.

Comment: @marc - The product is already there and so are the design mistakes. So, I am wondering what is the conceptual difference between having a boxed integer and a boxed DateTime?

Comment: @Mark none hugely; the problem is that having *no clue* (in advance) what the object is makes it more expensive to serialize. Even a "1 of these 27 types" is much cheaper than an open `object` - it just needs a little thought

Comment: @marc - All I want is model.Add(typeof(object), false).AddSubtype(typeof(int)) to work, rather than fail with an exception. Today, it fails because the code checks that the subtype is not primitive. For instance,  model.Add(typeof(object), false).AddSubtype(typeof(DateTime)) succeeds. I want int to be treated no different than DateTime with respect to the API. I still do not understand why there is a check for non primitive type there.

Comment: @marc - I have edited the post body.

Comment: @marc - http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/detail?id=175

Comment: @mark - ok, I see the usefulness. I think I can see a way for to work *without* the need to add an extra surrogate, though - essentially allowing it to recognise the type and use the existing "aux" code, which would have the advantage that it isn't too far apart from the regular layout. Let me have a play with that...

Comment: @mark - and also: thanks for taking the time to think about options, run trials, etc - it really is encouraging, thanks.

Comment: @marc - I am just trying to use protobuf-net. It is you whom I should thank for putting all this effort in providing us with this framework. Thanks.

Comment: @marc - I have opened another issue, somehow related to it - http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/detail?id=183